# What happens when aluminum reacts with tert butyl alcohol?

Tags: metal, alcohols

I wanted to know that what happens when aluminum reacts with tert butyl alcohol..?

Answer (score 1):

Organic Syntheses **1941**, *21*, 8

Aluminium and tBuOH heated in benzene in the presence of catalytic Mercuric Chloride forms Aluminium *tris* t-butoxide